# pthread kill after a certain time duration

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, visual-studio-2005, kill

I'm working with VS2005 C++ and I'm BRAND NEW to it.

I have a loop that creates several threads using the following statement -

```
rc = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, &Function, (void *)threadID);
```

I want to terminate all threads after a certain duration (say 5 minutes). How do I have a timer that kills all threads after this duration?

Comment: Why do you (think you) want to do this? Killing threads should be reserved for truly desperate situations.

Comment: How do you use POSIX threads in Windows OS?

Comment: Killing threads except main is part of the requirement..

Comment: If you need the threads to exit, you normally want to send them some sort of signal, to which they react by exiting normally.

Comment: If your requirements are written in such low level terms you need to have a chat about requirements. Do "they" not just want the worker threads to stop after a certain time?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, something like that:

```
pthread_t tid[thread_num] = {};
for(size_t i = 0 ; i < threads_num; ++i){
    pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, func, arg);
}
sleep(300);
for(size_t i = 0 ; i < threads_num; ++i){
    pthread_cancel(tid[i]);
}
```

Anyway, I don't know how to use pthread under VS 2005 =)

Yes, one important point - to be killed, your threads should reach a cancellation point. Some POSIX functions could be cancellation points, but it's better to call pthread_testcancel() in your thread (as they work about minutes, I think it's some kind of loop, just check that every iteration)

Comment: sleep function merely pauses the program right? I want the threads to contiue running till the specified time

Comment: You can start your threads in one more separate thread, that just will be waiting for timeout