# How to timeout a running function and all it's child processes on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, timeout, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

How to force a function and all it's child processes to timeout on Linux?

For example, how could `multiprocessed_func` be forced to finish after 10s:

```
import time

def multiprocessed_func(seconds):
    # Assume this a long running function which uses
    # multiprocessing internally and returns None.
    time.sleep(seconds)

try:
    multiprocessed_func(600)
except:
    print('took too long')
```

Comment: Are you expecting something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389644/pthread-kill-after-a-certain-time-duration) in python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Borrowing from the [psutil](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#functions) docs, we could inspect the current process and terminate or kill all the child processes after a given time.

```
def terminate_children(grace_period):
    procs = psutil.Process().children()
    for p in procs:
        p.terminate()
    gone, still_alive = psutil.wait_procs(procs, timeout=grace_period)
    for p in still_alive:
        p.kill()
    raise TimeoutError

try:
    multiprocessed_func(long_run=600)
    time.sleep(10)  # then timeout
    terminate_children(grace_period=2)
except TimeoutError:
    print('timed out')
    pass
```

Full example:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import psutil

def slow_worker(long_run):
    print('started')
    time.sleep(long_run)
    print('finished')

def multiprocessed_func(long_run):
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=slow_worker, args=(long_run,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
        print('starting', p.pid)

def on_terminate(proc):
    print('terminating {}, exit code {}'.format(proc, proc.returncode))

def terminate_children(grace_period):
    procs = psutil.Process().children()
    for p in procs:
        p.terminate()
    gone, still_alive = psutil.wait_procs(procs, timeout=grace_period, 
                                          callback=on_terminate)
    for p in still_alive:
        p.kill()
    raise TimeoutError

try:
    multiprocessed_func(long_run=600)
    time.sleep(10)
    terminate_children(grace_period=2)
except TimeoutError:
    print('timed out')
    pass
```

If terminating **all** the child processes in the current process is excessive because there are additional multiprocessed methods in the current process that need to be preserved, then we could wrap *multiprocessed_func* in another process.

```
def safe_run(timeout, grace_period):
    try:
        multiprocessed_func(long_run=600)
        time.sleep(timeout)
        terminate_children(grace_period)
    except TimeoutError:
        pass

timeout, grace_period = 10, 2
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=safe_run, args=(timeout, grace_period,))
p.start()
p.join()
p.terminate()
time.sleep(2)
if p.is_alive():
    p.kill()
```